# pH of 0.01 M glycine solution

Tags: equilibrium

The question is to find out the pH of $\pu{0.01M}$ glycine solution. It is given that $K_\mathrm{a1} = \pu{4.5*10^{-3}}$ and $K_\mathrm{a2} = \pu{1.7*10^{-7}}$.

Glycine is $\ce{NH2CH2COOH}$. The two $K_\mathrm{a}$ values correspond to the ionization of $\ce{COOH}$ and  $\ce{NH2}$. My idea was to average the two $K_\mathrm{a}$ values and take log to get pH. However this is not yielding the correct answer.

Comment: You've actually calculated the isoelectric point of glycine.

Comment: And $K_{a2}$ is for Ionization of $\ce{-NH3+}$, not for $\ce{NH2}$